# Splitting array in erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, erlang-shell

I wrote a simple functions to split an array to 2 parts.

```
split([], [], []) -> [[], []];
split([], [], Part2) -> [[], Part2];
split([], Part1, []) -> split([], [], Part1);
split([], Part1, Part2) -> [Part1, Part2];
split([Head | Tail], Part1, Part2) -> split(Tail, Part2, [Head | Part1]).
```

I tried to play with my function and I experienced a huge issue with that see the image below. The function works for a lot of example but if use for input `[4,9,2],[],[]` I got the following strange result `["\t",[2,4]]`.

[image]

Where is the issue?
Thanks for your answer and time.

Comment: Strings in Erlang are just lists of integers in ASCII range. ASCII code 9 means tabulation symbol, so the list [9] and string "\t" are equal for Erlang.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think that this behaviour is normal?

Comment: as achydragon says the 2 "\t" and [9] are 2 different ways to print the same value. It is a choice in the erlang shell, but it has no impact on the way you may want to use this result in a program, so yes, it is normal. You can compare the result of `io:format("~w~n",[[9]]).` and `io:format("~p~n",[[9]]).`

Comment: The `~p` "prettyprints its value and this is one of the things it does. It also breaks long output intelligently into multiple indented lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a behaviour of erlang:

```
8> [9].  
"\t"
9> ["\t"].
["\t"]
```

It is because, from erlang's POV, a string is just a series of number. erlang will try to print a number as a character if the number corresponds to a printable character.